# Matching 2 conditions in regexp_replace in postgres

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I need help getting my regex syntax right in Postgres regexp_replace:
My string:

```
1ABC 2ABC 3DEF 4DEF
```

My 2 Match/Replace conditions are:

```
 Replace: A OR C but not in front of 2
    or
 Replace: D OR F but not in front of 4
```

So I'm expecting to get:

```
"1A;BC; 2ABC; 3D;EF; 4DEF;"
```

My partial replace for condition 1 is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('1ABC 2ABC 3DEF 4DEF', '((?<!2)(A|C))','\1;','g' );
```

My 'Replace' is really an 'Insert' after the matched literal.

I just can not seem to be able to find the pattern for the 2nd condition, without breaking the whole thing.  Is this even possible in 1 statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT regexp_replace('1ABC 2ABC 3DEF 4DEF', '((\w*[^2]A|C)|(\w*[^4]D|F))','\1;','g');`

Result: `1A;BC; 2ABC; 3D;EF; 4DEF;`

Comment: And eurotrash is a genius! :-)   Thanks!